# parallel task and thread saftey in c#

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I have two separate tasks and two independent operations in each. I think t0 is thread safe but I am not sure about t1. Is it correct? The performance of concurrent dictionary is awful and I need to insert a lot of data to the collection.

```
var t0 = new Task[2]
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
    {
        list1=new sortedlist<int,int>(sortedlist1)
    }
    }),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
    {
        list2=new sortedlist<int,int>(sortedlist2)
    })
};
Task.WaitAll(t0)

var t1 = new Task[2]
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
    {
        foreach (var item in sortedlist1)
        {
            list1.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
        }
    }),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
    {
        foreach (var item in sortedlist2)
        {
            list2.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
        }
    })
};
Task.WaitAll(t1)
```

Comment: There seems to be nothing in common between tasks. Why do you think it is not thread-safe?

Comment: Exactly I am surprised because in t0 no data lost but in t1 part of my data lost

Comment: This is a http://codereview.stackexchange.com kind of question

Comment: @Alex No, it's not. codereview.SE is for code that actually works, but can be improved. This code doesn't work, according to mohammad.

Answer (score 1):

As written, this code doesn't work. The lists allocated in the first pair of tasks are not assigned to variables that are used by the second pair of tasks. Let's ignore that and just look at the general concepts here.

The two lists don't have to be allocated in separate threads to be used in separate threads. And you definitely do not need to waste effort allocating each list in a separate task. The lists can be allocated by the main thread, especially if the main thread is going to want to use the lists after the tasks are done. The only real issue is whether there is any possibility of one list being modified by two threads at the same time.

If list1 is only being read and written by task1, and list2 is only being read and written by task2, then you can do whatever you want to the lists in their respective tasks without any conflicts.

Use Task.WaitAll as you are already doing to wait for both tasks to complete. After both tasks are complete, the main thread can take control of list1 and list2 to make further modifications. One common follow-up operation after a set of parallel executed tasks such as this is to merge the work of the multiple tasks into a final output. (see "MapReduce")

Comment: Although two operations in t1 is independent and but data is missed during the second task

Comment: According to this explanation, You think multi-task is not useful in this case and I should use sequential programming. Because I thought If I use multi-task to fill list, the speed will increase

Comment: I said that multitasking is not necessary for allocating the list objects. There may be value in performing the list.add() to multiple independent lists in parallel. After that is done, you have N lists from N tasks. Then what? Do you intend to perform N lookups whenever you need to find something in the lists? Probably not. A common pattern is to merge the outputs of the multiple tasks into one list after all the tasks are finished. This is the "mapreduce" pattern.

Comment: A caveat when working with multiple threads / tasks is that you need to make sure that the work you are assigning to each thread is significant enough to justify the human and machine costs of using multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

This seems ok - you're not accessing the same variable across tasks.  The tasks in t1[] won't run until the tasks from t0[] are finished.

You could use Parallel.Do() instead of making the tasks in the array and then waiting for them to finish - this makes your intentions more clear and avoids a lot of the array-based ceremony.

I assume you've made up up an example rather than this being actual code?

Comment: I wrote this code in static method that returns a class variable that contains 2 sorted lists.